# C variable initialize overhead

Tags: c

Think about below code:

```
int i=0;//initialize here
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
    //... do something here
}
```

since i will be initialized in for loop, we no need to initialize it when define it. but if we do initialize, any overhead after translate to binary code?

Comment: This kind of "optimization" is never going to make any difference on a modern compiler. You can easily verify this on your target platform(s) if it matters.

Comment: The world's code would be incredibly slow if things like this mattered. Your compiler's optimizer will deal with this. Even better, declare the variable in the for-loop.

Comment: depends on how much the code gets optimized. It should get optimized away by any uptodate compiler if optimization is enabled and shouldn't have much of an impact on performance anyways.

Comment: Well, *theoretically*, without any compiler optimizations, and with a dumb straight-forward compiler the initializer value has to be a part of the binary, impacting it's size along with a startup code performing the actual assignment. It should be noted, that uninitialized variables with a static storage class will somewhat suffer from similar issue, as they have to be reset to zero by the startup code.

Comment: Once a while ago, before `-O65535` was common, there were "native compilers" that does not do any optimization (ones that do are called "optimization compilers"). At that time, this kind of tuning is useful. But now things are different, because only a few optimization compilers survived.

Comment: This is trivial for an optimizing compiler to elide. Think about it a bit. You basically have `int i = 0; i = 0;`. You don't even have to be as smart as a modern optimizer to see that one of those is redundant! But that doesn't mean you should write code like this; it is confusing for humans that are reading it. In fact, you should keep the declaration of variables to as limited a scope as possible. Thus, you should write the loop as `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { ... }`, so that `i` is not even accessible outside of the loop body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler does not dynamically allocate auto variables. There is no 'init', so to speak. Therefore, there is no real purpose behind moving variable declarations around other than preventing scoping issues.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will generally be able to make short work of a simple case like that. Best approach is to put the int i=0 inside the for loop. If you need to use the i after the loop, then init it before hand and leave the init part of the for loop empty.

Comment: I think it is bad advice to tell anyone reading the code to look somewhere else to see what the initial value of the control variable is to be.

Answer (score 0):

to verify overhead you want to generate **assembly language**.
You can do this via

**gcc -c -O0  -S**

you will need to use the `-c` flag, and and it will result in a file named `yourcode.s`.

Rename each assembly language .s file before redoing the gcc command with each compiler option for optimization, **-O1, -O2, -O3**.

From these assembly language files you can then determine exactly what overhead there would be and if it is significant.

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   int i;
   int j;

   i=5543644;    /* to have or not to have this line*/
   for ( i = 0; i < 2342465; i++ )
      j = i;

   return 0;
}
```

Given this code example, when compiling with optimization **-O0** for the case where `i=5543644` exists and does not exist, the only difference in the two assembly language files generated is one line which is

```
movl    $5543644, -8(%rbp)
```

which is the copying of the data value  **5543644** into the memory address of **i**.  I used a value other than zero to make it obvious in the assembly language.

when using compiler optimization **-O3**, the resulting two assembly language files are **identical**.  This proves that optimization results in the compiler identifying the `i=5543644;` directly before the `for` loop to be useless, and the resulting `movl` line found when doing **-O0** is not generated.

this was tested using gcc 4.3.4.

From your simple code example of just `int i = 0;` one does not need to do this to know there is no real world overhead, but as code gets very large and complex, if the useless `i = 5543644;` is not directly before the for loop then it may not get optimized out. The source code and assembly language would have to be scrutinized to make that determination.

If this type of data assignment does happen, for example within nested for loops and within OPENMP or other parallelization directives causing it happen millions or billions of times depending on the code, then yes it would cause overhead.  How significant that may be could be quite subjective.